# Why is infeasibility of linear programming considered to be an NP problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, linear-programming, co-np, simplex

I recently came across this question, and the way I think people usually go about this is to find a certificate that answers 'yes' to the decision problem 'Is this LP infeasible?' Or, given a certificate, verify if that yields infeasibility or not. I know of the theorem that says Ax = b is infeasible if there exists y such that ATy = 0 and yTb = 1. (AT = transpose of A). So given a y, we can check in polynomial time if these two conditions hold, and that is why the infeasibility problem is in NP. Am I missing something, or is this a good enough approach?

Comment: This only shows that a solution can be checked in polynomial time. Not that the problem cannot be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you'll also have to prove that: (1) the "infeasible if" is an "infeasible iff", (2) the "size" of $y$ (the number of bits needed to represent it) is polynomial in the size of $A,b$, and (3) you can find $y$ in polynomial time.